# Flutter set state not updating my UI with new data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `ListView.builder` widget wrapped inside a `RefreshIndicator` and then a `FutureBuilder`. Refreshing does not update my list, I have to close the app and open it again but the refresh code does the same as my `FutureBuilder`.

Please see my code below, when I read it I expect the widget tree to definitely update.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  taskListFuture= TaskService().getTasks();
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(builder: (context, taskData, child) {
      return FutureBuilder(
          future: taskListFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              taskData.tasks = (snapshot.data as ApiResponseModel).responseBody;
              return RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: () async {
                  var responseModel = await TaskService().getTasks();
                  setState(() {
                    taskData.tasks = responseModel.responseBody;
                  });
                },
                child: ListView.builder(
...
...
```

Let me know if more code is required, thanks in advance!

Points

- I am using a StatefulWidget
- Task data is a class that extends ChangeNotifier
- When I debug the refresh I can see the new data in the list, but the UI does not update

getTasks()

```
  Future<ApiResponseModel> getTasks() async {
    try {
      var _sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var userId = _sharedPreferences.getString(PreferencesModel.userId);

      var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("$apiBaseUrl/$_controllerRoute?userId=$userId"),
        headers: await authorizeHttpRequest(),
      );

      var jsonTaskDtos = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var taskDtos= List<TaskDto>.from(
          jsonTaskDtos.map((jsonTaskDto) => TaskDto.fromJson(jsonTaskDto)));
      return ApiResponseModel(
          responseBody: taskDtos,
          isSuccessStatusCode: isSuccessStatusCode(response.statusCode));
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How does `TaskService().getTasks()` look?

Comment: @rckrd I have just added it now

Answer (score 2):

The issue here seems to be that you are updating a property that is not part of your StatefulWidget state.

```
setState(() {
  taskData.tasks = responseModel.responseBody;
});
```

That sets a property part of `TaskData`.
My suggestion is to only use the `Consumer` and refactor `TaskService` so it controls a list of `TaskData` or similar. Something like:

Provider

```
class TaskService extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<TaskData> _data;

  load() async {
    this.data = await _fetchData();
  }

  List<TaskData> get data => _data;

  set data(List<TaskData> data) {
    _data = data;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Widget

```
class MyTaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskService>(builder: (context, service, child) {
      return RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () {
            service.getTasks();
          },
          child: ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: service.data.length,
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     return MyTaskItem(data:service.data[index]);
                   },
                 ),
         ); 
    });
  }
}
```

and make sure to call `notifyListeners()` in the service.getTasks() method to make the `Consumer` rebuild

Comment: Thanks to your comment I refactored TaskData to have a method initialising the tasks list and calling `notifyListeners()` which meant I wouldn't be making an extra call to the API. I found out though that the problem was me passing taskListFuture as a variable to the `FutureBuilder` rather than calling the method itself. I had done this because a youtube video said that was best practice. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! But why do you have both `Consumer` and `FutureBuilder`? @steve

Comment: I use the FutureBuilder for the async API call and Consumer so I can access the taskData in the widget tree. I am new to Flutter, if I am missing something or doing something inefficiently please let me know, I always wanna do better! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It just that `FutureBuilder` is not needed. `Consumer` will rebuild when notifyListeners() is called. So if you just make sure to call notifyListeners() when new data is available and your widget will update. You can use a StatelessWidget to wrap your `Consumer`.  Load the data when you first create the provider `ChangeNotifierProvider<YourModel>(create: (_) => YourModel()..load())`

Answer (score 0):

I think (someone will correct me if I'm wrong) the problem is that you are using the `FutureBuilder`, once it's built, you need to refresh to whole widget for the FutureBuilder to listen to changes. I can suggest a `StreamBuilder` that listens to any changes provided from the data model/api/any kind of stream of data. Or better yet, you can use some sort of state management like `Provider` and use `Consumer` from the Provider package that notifies the widget of any changes that may occurred.

Comment: Very true, I use the refresh indicator so that the user can refresh the data when they want. The TaskData also extends ChangeNotifier and I use the `Consumer` widget as seen. When I remove/add items to the list it updates. It's only the refresh that does not update the list with new data.

Comment: When you hot restart, the UI is updated? The only problem is when you do this with the `RefreshIndicator`, correct?

Comment: I just tried this with my app and my custom API endpoint, works fine. Can you post the `TaskService().getTasks()` method please?

Comment: I have added `getTasks()` to the question, thanks GM